# How to turn a Pandas column into array and transpose it?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, transpose

I have a Pandas dataframe called 'training_set' that resembles the screenshot below:

[image]

I try to turn the 'label' column into array and transpose it. I tried doing `Y_train=np.asarray(training_set['label'])` but what I got is a horizontal array that resembles the screenshot below, which is not what I want.

[image]

I want the array to display vertically just like the screenshot below (The screenshot has 2 variables per row. My desired output should only contain 1 variable, the 'label', per row.)

[image]

Any suggestion or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### pandas >= 0.24

Use `DataFrame.to_numpy()`, the new Right Way to extract a numpy array:

```
training_set[['label']].to_numpy()
```

---

**pandas < 0.24**

Slice out your column as a single columned `DataFrame` (using `[[...]]`), not as a `Series`:

```
Y_train = np.asarray(training_set[['label']])
```

Or,

```
Y_train = training_set[['label']].values
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to reshape your array to shape `(-1,1)`, which means "infer number of rows, force to 1 column":

```
Y_train = np.array(training_set['label']).reshape(-1,1)
```

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
Y_train = training_set['label'].values[:, None]
```